# Sort model relationship date

Tags: php, sorting, model, relationship, phalcon

I have two tables:

```
Discussion:
╔════╦════════════════╗
║ id ║     name       ║
╠════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Stackoverflow  ║
║  2 ║ Stackoverflow2 ║
╚════╩════════════════╝

Message:
╔════╦════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ discussion_id  ║  content  ║    date    ║
╠════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║       1        ║ message 1 ║  jan 2011  ║
║  2 ║       1        ║ message 2 ║  jan 2012  ║
║  3 ║       2        ║ message 3 ║  jan 2013  ║
║  4 ║       2        ║ message 4 ║  jan 2014  ║
╚════╩════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

The results of `Discussion::find()` should be sorted like this:

```
Stackoverflow2   
Stackoverflow
```

Because "Stackoverflow2" is more recent than "Stackoverflow" according to the dates in the `Message` table.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query must be like following,

`select discussion.id, discussion.name from Discussion join message on message.discussion_id = Discussion.id order by message.date`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, with the syntax Phalcon, it's become :

```
$discussions = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
->from('Phalcon\Model\DiscussionModel')
->join('Phalcon\Model\MessageModel')
->orderBy("Phalcon\Model\MessageModel.cts DESC")
->getQuery()
->execute();
```